# How To Find Matrix B Given Matrix AB and A?

Tags: matrices

Matrix A:

\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ -2 & 5 \end{bmatrix}

Product of Matrices AB:

\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -1 \\ 6 & -9 & 3\end{bmatrix}

Find Matrix B?

---

I am assuming that matrix B is 2x3 matrix but how does one go about finding it ?

Comment: Multiply $A^{-1}$ by $AB$.

Comment: $A^{-1} A B = B$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

(1) Write down your matrix $B$ as a matrix of unknowns.  Then do the matrix multiplication of $A$ and $B$ and equate it to the known $AB$, giving you a system of equations to solve.

Or

(2) If matrix $A$ is invertible, use its inverse.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $A^{-1}AB=B$ where $A^{-1}$ is the [inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Methods_of_matrix_inversion) of the (square) matrix $A$